# Output of the 2 lists mixed

Tags: javascript, php, html

Recently i got task on my work which is quite "too big" for me.

I am looking to create generator for mixing two elements.

1. The list of locations
2. The code or text
3. Output will enter location to code/text for each new line

This is the current work on HTML

[image: Screenshot of generator]

Because i am pretty noob at PHP can somebody explain what functions should i use to make this generator work?

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:50px;">Generate Locations       </h1>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">

    <h3>Input locations in new line each</h3>

    <textarea rows="20" style="width:100%">
    </textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h3>Input code. Use "??Location" to replace.</h3>

    <textarea rows="20" style="width:100%">
    </textarea>
</div>

<center><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:20px;" >Generate</button></center>

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h3>Output</h3>

    <textarea rows="20" style="width:100%">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: is the screenshot you provided show current working or it is your requirement? plus is php necessary because if you only want to output result, it can be done via js too

Comment: Screenshot shows my html work so far, Now i need php functionality for it. And yeah Javascript is fine with me as well. I just need help over which functions i can use, how to take first list, detect ??location and export

Comment: Is there any special reason you want to do this in PHP? It can be done just as easily in javascript, not requiring a submit and page load as a result.

Comment: If Javascript is easier then i don't need PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, give your textareas IDs so you can reference them easily:

```
<textarea rows="20" style="width:100%" id="locations">
</textarea>

<textarea rows="20" style="width:100%" id="inputcode">
</textarea>

<textarea rows="20" style="width:100%" id="output">
</textarea>
```

The rest is Javascript:

```
<script>
    function generateLocations() {
        var locations = document.getElementById("locations").value.split(/[\r\n]+/g);
        var inputcode = document.getElementById("inputcode").value;

        var output_text = "";

        locations.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
            output_text += inputcode.replace(/\?\?Location/g, item) + "\n";
        });

        document.getElementById("output").value = output_text;
    }
</script>
```

You can call this function with your button:

```
<button onclick="generateLocations()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:20px;">Generate</button>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I figure it out for function and onclick and it' works perfectly.One thing only, how can i add so the output goes to new line for each?

Comment: Checkmark is mandatory of course, but THANK YOU for saving my a** on this is what's matter the most :)

Answer (score 0):

add id `locations`, `code` and `output` to location's, code's and output's textarea respectively.

add this in script tag

```
function generate(){
   var lta = document.getElementById("locations");
   var cta = document.getElementById("code");

   var locations = lta.split("\n");
   var codes = cta.split("\n");
  var final = "";
   codes.forEach(function(code){
      locations.forEach(function(loc){
          var codeCopy = code;
          final += codeCopy.replace("??Location", loc) + "\n";
      })
   })
  var out = document.getElementById("output");
  out.innerText = final;
}
```

call it on `onclick` of generate button

Comment: Thank You Mohammad, i didn't check your code, because Pharaoh has provided me with the working on. Thanks for your time!